# Get ViewCount in Search.List - Youtube Data API v3

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

Recently, I work with `youtube API v3` for `Android`. I use [Search.List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) when I want to retrieve list of videos from a keyword. I can find a lot of information from result (items/snippet), however I can't find `viewCount` of each video. Looking detail at this API, I see a field named: `order` and I can order by `rating`, `viewCount`, etc. IMO there should has a way to retrieve `viewCount` when searching. Does anyone know it? Is it possible to give an example? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

See my explanation [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098954/get-view-count-in-youtbue-v3-api-for-java)

viewCount can be retrieved from the Videos-->list and not from Search-->list.

Comment: Then I should call video-list for every id that I got from search-list?