# Get View Count in YouTube V3 API for java

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I get the information of how many views a certain video of YouTube has by providing the videoID of it using `Java API`?

for example in the code sample that their provide they print different properties. How can I add printing the **view Count**?

Java code:

```
        SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
        ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

        // Confirm that the result represents a video. Otherwise, the
        // item will not contain a video ID.
        if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
            Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();

            System.out.println(" Video Id" + rId.getVideoId());
            System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
```

here is a very similar question to mine, also unanswered:
[Get ViewCount in Search.List - Youtube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240475/get-viewcount-in-search-list-youtube-data-api-v3)

update 30/9:
According to Youtube API [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) the video resource may contain the following parts:

- snippet
- contentDetails
- fileDetails
- player
- processingDetails
- recordingDetails
- statistics
- status
- suggestions
- topicDetails

but in the [SearchResult](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/SearchResult.html) object only expose getSnippet() out of all of them

I also couldn't use a different *part* except the 'snippet' in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/list/m/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=statistics&q=like%20a%20virgin&_h=2&) that google provides.

So maybe all these statistics properties are not supported yet by API V3??

Answer (score 2):

OK I got it the code to do it is:

```
YouTube.Videos.List list = youtube.videos().list("statistics");
list.setId("kffacxfA7G4");
list.setKey("your private API KEY");            
Video v = list.execute().getItems().get(0);
        System.out.println("The view count is: "+v.getStatistics().getViewCount());
```

This video BTW exceed the billion views - Justim Bieber rules! (-;

Answer (score 1):

After getting the "id" here, you should do a [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call, to get video properties like "viewcount".

Here's sample: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/GeolocationSearch.java#L142

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't understand. Your referenced example doesn't include calling for viewCount at all. 
I looked at the API the viewCount is not a property member of 'SearchResult' https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/SearchResult.html and niether of 'SearchResultSnippet' - https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/SearchResultSnippet.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a video id, you could make a Video-List get call with the below query parameters.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={Video_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

You could try Youtube api v3 tool to check https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list