# Retrieving details from a YouTube video given the URL

Tags: java, youtube-api

For example, given the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE which is a video about installing the Java JDK.

Using Java and the YouTube-API, how can I get information such as length, title, and views?

I looked and I found https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries but it's outdated and I'm not sure exactly how to use it.

Forgive my ignorance as I'm new to Java. Thanks.

Comment: Did you already have a look at the code samples from the [Youtube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java)?

Comment: @Mr Tsjolder, yes, am I missing it?

Comment: I never used the API myself, but maybe you can find what you're looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098954/get-view-count-in-youtbue-v3-api-for-java/26105106#26105106)... If this is the case, consider to flag your own question as a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Videos:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and specify the video ID to retrieve video information for a specific video. For example:

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
        new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("video-test").build();

final String videoId = "Hl-zzrqQoSE";
YouTube.Videos.List videoRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet,statistics,contentDetails");
videoRequest.setId(videoId);
videoRequest.setKey("{YOUR-API-KEY}");
VideoListResponse listResponse = videoRequest.execute();
List<Video> videoList = listResponse.getItems();

Video targetVideo = videoList.iterator().next();
```

`targetVideo` would then hold information related to your video. You can get information such as title, view count and duration from this object:

```
    targetVideo.getSnippet().getTitle();
    targetVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount();
    targetVideo.getContentDetails().getDuration();
```

The following imports are required:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on line 


`VideoListResponse listResponse = videoRequest.execute();`


It says:

`cannot find symbol

symbol: execute()

location: variable videoRequest of type YoutTube.Videos.List`

Any ideas?

Comment: You may be missing some imports. I have added the ones I have to the answer above.

Comment: I have added those imports and I am still receiving an error at videoRequest.execute()

Comment: Strange I assume you have all the latest v3 api libraries

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks for all the help!