# Need help to get YouTube Java API code working

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to make a simple program that calls the API to check video views after finding this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129580/1799985) but have run into a bit of trouble. I found the code needed to initialise a `YouTube` object here (https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/GeolocationSearch.java#L90)

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-geolocationsearch-sample").build();
```

I noticed that the code requires the class `Auth`, which is defined in the import

`import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;`

This is in an `api-samples` repo from Google and not included in the YouTube API dependency I have defined in my Maven `pom.xml` in my Eclipse project. I decided to just copy the `Auth.java` file and place it in my project's `src/main/java` folder but now I have another problem: 2 imports in `Auth.java` cannot be resolved. These are the ones:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

You can see the entirety of `Auth.java`  [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java).

In case it'll help here is the dependency definition from my `pom.xml` file:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
      <version>v3-rev20201202-1.31.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Thank you for taking time to read this, and I hope you can find a solution for me. :)

Comment: Have a look at the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/pom.xml) that came along with the API sample programs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stvar's comment I looked at the `pom.xml` file from the `api-samples` repo and found what I was missing was a Google OAuth client thing. I added the following code to my `pom.xml` and the imports were resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```