# How to access YouTube view count with Java API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129580/1799985) that shows how to get a video's view count with the Java YouTube API but clearly some things must have changed over the last 7 years or so because I can't figure out the code.

This line

```
YouTube.Videos.List list = youtube.videos().list("statistics");
```

produces an error in Eclipse because the `list` method from the class `Videos`(at least in the current API version) has a parameter of type `List<String>`not `String`...so can someone show me how to achieve my goal using the current API seeing as the code linked above is invalid due to changes to the API?

EDIT: Here is how I have defined my dependency for the YouTube API in my `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev20201202-1.31.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Indeed, when using the generated Java libraries [Google Java API Client Services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services) -- specifically [that corresponding to YouTube Data API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-youtube/v3) --, the specification of the [`list`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-youtube/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.Videos.html#list-java.util.List-) method is precisely as Eclipse shows.

Comment: Not that this is of importance for you (as an user of the client library), but fact is that the YouTube Data API's [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint has its request parameter [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) of type `string` (of which value is specified as a comma-separated list of one or more video resource properties). The client library abstracts the type of this request parameter as `List<String>`.

Comment: So, how do I get the view count with the latest API version then? Like, what am I supposed to pass to the `list` method then? The old version in the question I linked has the `String` "statistics" do I put that inside a `List` and pass it or have I got it all wrong?

Comment: Have the `part` parameter set to: `Arrays.asList("statistics")`.

Comment: Yay, I got the program working! I had to use `Arrays.asList` for the argument for the `list.setId` method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a little help from stvar and of course the old question I linked to in my question I figured out what I needed to do. Here is the working code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.*;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-view-count-test").build();
    
        YouTube.Videos.List list = youtube.videos().list(Arrays.asList("statistics"));
        list.setId(Arrays.asList("kffacxfA7G4"));
        String apiKey = "[redacted]";
        list.setKey(apiKey);            
        Video v = list.execute().getItems().get(0);
        System.out.println("The view count is: "+v.getStatistics().getViewCount());
    }
}
```

The `Auth` class that is used in my code is taken from [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java), part of Google's API samples